# A nonstandard polynomial interpolation problem

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I thought I know the properties of polynomials quite thoroughly. But...

I am looking for a recipe to construct, for any given finite set $S$ whose elements are sets of $N$ real vectors of length $n$ elements, a space $P_{Nn}(S)$ of polynomials of dimension $O(N)$ (independent of the size of $S$) such that every real-valued map from some $W\in S$ can be interpolated by some element of $P(W)$ (possibly in more than one way).

One can take $P_{N1}(W)$ to consist of the univariate polynomials of degree less than $N$.

But already the case $n=2$ is beyond what I was able to settle in a reasonable amount of time. Is it perhaps impossible to achieve?

Comment: Could you relax the dimension to $O(nN)$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Initially any dimension of a size independent of the size of $S$ is fine, so that I can learn about the underlying ideas employed. But for practical efficiency I ultimately need a bound independent of $n$, which could become large.

Comment: In that case I'll comment rather than answer: $O(nN)$ can be achieved with Lagrange interpolation with one subtlety. We interpolate $W$ with weighted selector polynomials $f_s$ chosen so that $f_s(s) = 1$ and $f_s(t) = 0$ for $t \in S \setminus \{s\}$. $f_s$ can be built by multiplying Lagrange selectors in each dimension subject to working on *distinct* projections onto the dimension (so that if $s = (1, \ldots)$ and $t = (1, \ldots)$ we don't get a contribution from $t$ in the first dimension).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I don't understand. $S$ is a set of sets, how can it be the argument of a polynomial??

Comment: Correct $t \in S \setminus \{s\}$ to $t \in W \setminus \{s\}$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: But $f_s(s)=1$???

Comment: $s$, not $S$. I admit that I should probably have called it $w$.